# Excluding executables in winsxs folder

Tags: antivirus

I am facing a big problem since there are many `msbuild.exe` files in `.Netframework` and `winsxs` folders and I don't know if it is required to set all of them as trusted in the antivirus.

The path changes server to server and hence it makes life harder!

Thanks

Comment: Start with your actual problem. Is `msbuild.exe` a false positive in your dumb anti-virus?

Comment: I am having some problems regarding the exclusion list of the AV. The AV is ignoring some exclusion rules in some scanning threads, yet the executable name is the same. So I doubt if "winsxs" is the source of problem

Comment: @YasserSobhdel - Sounds like you should replace the AV if it won't even honor its own exclusion rules.

Comment: @Ramhound - It seems that exclusion is not enough, we may trust applications and also any stream coming to/going from the application which requires full path. I may close this thread now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not disable the antivirus on this folder. If you have performance issues [cleanup WinSXS](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-8/cleanup-the-winsxs-folder-in-windows-8-7/).

In case of a false positive:

- contact antivirus company OR
- check it with an online scanner

Comment: Actually they are build machines with Microsoft TFS on them.

I don't know if the antivirus is blocking operation of this executable or not, yet due to some poor performance of the antivirus in other situations, my options are quite limited in this situation. And since the sole server role is "building .net applications", I am in sheer need of a way to eliminate any possible clogging scenario regarding the antivirus.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you been asking @StackOverflow? Maybe those guys know more...

Comment: Isn't StackOverflow for development questions? I doubt my question conform to the forum rules.

Comment: Yeah, but i think they have more experience with TFS. Just ask about TFS and AV - they won't bite you ;-)